# Creating an Address book with different users.

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make an Address book with different users in which they can log in with their username and password. And they can store the information like contact id, first name, last name, phone etc. I want each user to have his own address book.
Can someone please explain how I create different address book for different users.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Create a database. take a primary id to each user or provide unique id.Then create another table fill the fields that you want(address book).Match the user who logged in and  and with that another table(foreign key relationship).
When you login ..it checks with db then allows.After that you have to use insert ,update keywords for further process to put data in db.That particular unique id/primary key is used to fetch the related data(address book fields) of that user.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not a good question for StackOverflow but I will still roughly explain it to you.

You will need two different tables for this. The first one will be used for login details and the second one will record user's address book.

For example:

Table `auth` will have 3 columns `id, username, password`

Table `addressBook` will have `contact id, first name, last name, phone` etc and also have one more which will be called `userID`

Whenever any user eneter the data in `addressBook` their `userID` from `auth` table coloum `id` will be stored along with it. Now you can display their own data to the users.

If you have anymore question ask in comment here.